# Update a undefined proprety on mongoose schema and save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have defined a user schema like below

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  location: String,
  picture: String,
  isFirstNamePublic: { type: Boolean, required: false, Default: false },
  isLastNamePublic: { type: Boolean, required: false, Default: false },
  isEmailPublic: { type: Boolean, required: false, Default: false },
  isLocationPublic: { type: Boolean, required: false, Default: false },
  isPicturePublic: { type: Boolean, required: false, Default: false },
  passwordHash: { type: String, required: true },
  userRoles: [{businessId: String, role: {type: String, uppercase: true, enum: ['INDIVIDUAL_USER', 'BUSINESS_EMPLOYEE', 'BUSINESS_ADMIN', 'CLIENT', 'PLATFORM_EMPLOYEE']}}],
  interestedOfferCategory: String,
  linkedSocialNetwork: {type: String, required: false, uppercase: true, enum: ['FACEBOOK', 'TWITTER', 'LINKEDIN']},
  linkedSocialNetworkUserId: String,
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpired: Boolean
});
```

Now If I want to update any field that is undefined I am not able to update. For ex: I have a user document saved like below

```
{ _id: 54c439395ff4ede519912ea8,
  firstName: 'updated first name',
  lastName: 'test',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  interestedOfferCategory: 'testcategory',
  passwordHash: '$2a$10$S1zqmQHQ7Sd/qJjtryfzFua4Rn6Xi/oCHsJP9mLfyUnMg/gNV/u3K',
  __v: 0,
  userRoles: 
   [ { businessId: '123',
       role: 'INDIVIDUAL_USER',
       _id: 54c439395ff4ede519912ea9 } ] }
```

Now I extend this document to add resetPasswordToken like below

```
var updatedUser = _.extend(user, {resetPasswordToken: token, revokeSessionTokenExpired: false});
```

And If I try to save the document the values of resetPasswordToken and resetPasswordTokenExpired is not updated.

```
updatedUser.save(cb);
```

The above line not updating values.

What am I missing here?

Comment: revokeSessionTokenExpired != resetPasswordTokenExpired

Comment: @NeilLunn I didn't get you?

Comment: Your code uses the wrong property name it says "revokeSessionTokenExpired", which does not exist on the document.

Comment: @NeilLunn Even if I changed it to `resetPasswordExpired` the document is not updated

Answer (score 0):

The object 'user' that is being extended looks a mongoose model object that was instantiated using the 'new' keyword. If that is true you have to call do var objUser = user.toObject() and extend objUser.

```
  var mongooseUser = require('/path/mongooseUserSchemaFileName.js');

  var userDoc = { 
                    _id: 54c439395ff4ede519912ea8,
                    firstName: 'updated first name',
                    lastName: 'test',
                    email: 'test@test.com',
                    interestedOfferCategory: 'testcategory',
                    passwordHash: '$2a$10$S1zqmQHQ7Sd/qJjtryfzFua4Rn6Xi/oCHsJP9mLfyUnMg/gNV/u3K',
                    __v: 0,
                    userRoles: [ 
                          { businessId: '123',
                            role: 'INDIVIDUAL_USER',
                            _id: 54c439395ff4ede519912ea9 
                          } 
                               ] 
                    }

   var tempUser = _.extend(userDoc, {resetPasswordToken: token,     revokeSessionTokenExpired: false});

   var updateUser = new mongooseUser(tempUser);
   updatedUser.save(cb);
```

Comment: Except you never called `.toObject()` anywhere here. So I think you should show the OP exactly where they have to do that. This also reads more like a "Question" rather than an "Answer" without really looking to see that it is intended as an answer. You should change the wording before someone mistakes this for your own "Question" and flags it for removal.